# What's the best way to check the version of a library on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, libraries, distro

I am sure there are several ways to do this, but is there a tool built into Ubuntu or a recommended way to check the version of any given library you have installed on an ubuntu server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off. Sometimes when people talk about libraries they are talking about .deb packages that *provide* libraries to other packages. We'll deal with that case first. The other context you hear the term library used in is the traditional `.so` [shared object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_object) sense. We'll deal with that second.

`apt-cache depends <package_name>` will return a list of packages that are dependencies for `<package name>`. Packages are not necessarily congruous with libraries (i.e., libraries in the sense of linkable `.so` files), but in Debian and Ubuntu libraries are *generally* packaged as `lib<something>`. If you do a `dpkg -l |grep <library package name>` you can find which package containing which libraries is installed.

```
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$  apt-cache depends perl
perl
  Depends: perl-base
  Depends: perl-modules
  Depends: libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libdb4.7
  Depends: libgdbm3
  Depends: zlib1g
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ dpkg -l |grep libc6
ii  libc6                                    2.11.2-10                         Embedded GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-dev                                2.11.2-10                         Embedded GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
```

Or you can go the other way. If you're wondering what package required the package `libwww-perl` you can use this handy little perl script to return a list of `libwww-perl` reverse dependencies that are **also** installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use AptPkg::Cache;
my $cache = AptPkg::Cache->new;

my $pkg = $ARGV[0]
    or die 'supply a package name as the first arg';

my @acrd = split /\s+/, `apt-cache rdepends $pkg`;

my $state;
for (@acrd) {
    unless ( $_ eq 'Reverse' or $_ eq 'Depends:' ) {
        $state = $cache->{$_}->{'CurrentState'};
        print "$_\n" if $state eq 'Installed';
    }
}
```

Now the `.so` shared object files are a little different. I like to use a combination of `ldd` and `apt-file`. Let's say I'm interested in the object files linked against `ls`:

```
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff8b05d000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fcfb7e24000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fcfb7c1c000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fcfb7a14000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fcfb76b3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fcfb74af000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fcfb8057000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fcfb7292000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fcfb708e000)
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ apt-file search libattr.so.1
    ia32-libs: /lib32/libattr.so.1
    ia32-libs: /lib32/libattr.so.1.1.0
    libattr1: /lib/libattr.so.1
    libattr1: /lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ dpkg -l |grep libattr1
    ii  libattr1                                 1:2.4.44-2                        Extended attribute shared library
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ file /lib/libattr.so.1
/lib/libattr.so.1: symbolic link to `libattr.so.1.1.0'
kelliott@mis-ke-lnx:~$ file /lib/libattr.so.1.1.0
/lib/libattr.so.1.1.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

As you can see our good friend `ls` has quite a few libraries linked against it. `libattr.so.1` handles file attributes if I remember correctly. Doing an `apt-file search` against it shows that it was installed by two packages `ia32-libs` and `libattr1` (one for 32bit and one for 64bit). And on my system it looks like the `libattr1` package (at version 1:2.4.44-2) installed the libattr.so shared object file, which upon further investigation is at version 1.1.0.